# How to improve performance of distribution to std::function listeners?

Tags: c++, c++14

In short, is there any obvious way to make the `distributor.distribute()` call in the code below run any faster?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <typeindex>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <chrono>


// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
// Things to get passed around
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
class Base {
public:
  virtual ~Base() {};
};
class Derived : public Base {};

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
// Base class for our Handler class so we can store them in a container
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
class BaseHandler
{
public:
  virtual ~BaseHandler() {};
  virtual void handle(std::shared_ptr<const Base> ptr) = 0;
};

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
// Handler class to wrap a std::function. This is helpful because it
// allows us to add metadata to the function call such as call priority
// (not implemented here for simplification)
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename T>
class Handler : public BaseHandler
{
public:
  Handler(std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<const T>)> handlerFn)
  : handlerFn(handlerFn) {};
  void handle(std::shared_ptr<const Base> ptr) override {
    handlerFn(std::static_pointer_cast<const T>(ptr));
  }
private:
  std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<const T>)> handlerFn;
};

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
// Distributor keeps a record of listeners by type and calls them when a
// corresponding object of that type needs to be distributed.
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
class Distributor
{
public:
  template <typename T>
  void addHandler(std::shared_ptr<Handler<T>> handler)
  {
    handlerMap[std::type_index(typeid(T))].emplace_back(handler);
  }
  void distribute(std::shared_ptr<const Base> basePtr)
  {
    const Base& base = *basePtr;
    std::type_index typeIdx(typeid(base));

    for(auto& handler : handlerMap[typeIdx])
    {
      handler->handle(basePtr);
    }
  }
private:
  std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BaseHandler>>> handlerMap;
};

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
// Benchmarking code
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------

// Test handler function
void handleDerived(std::shared_ptr<const Derived> derived) { }

int main ()
{
  size_t iters = 10000000;
  size_t numRuns = 10;

  Distributor distributor;

  // add our test handler
  distributor.addHandler(std::make_shared<Handler<Derived>>(&handleDerived));

  std::cout << "Raw Func Call\t|\tDistributor\t|\tRatio" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "-------------\t|\t-----------\t|\t-----" << std::endl;

  for(size_t i = 0; i < numRuns; i++)
  {
    auto evt = std::make_shared<Derived>();

    // time raw function calls
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < iters; i++) {
      handleDerived(evt);
    }
    auto d = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start);

    // time calls through the distributor
    start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < iters; i++) {
      distributor.distribute(evt);
    }
    auto d2 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start);

    std::cout << d.count() << "\t\t|\t" << d2.count() << "\t\t|\t" << (d2*1.0/d) << std::endl;
  }


}
```

The results on my Windows 10 machine running MinGW-W64 g++ 8.1.0 optimized with the `-O3` flag:

```
Raw Func Call   |       Distributor     |       Ratio
-------------   |       -----------     |       -----
256             |       1256            |       4.90625
258             |       1224            |       4.74419
273             |       1222            |       4.47619
246             |       1261            |       5.12602
270             |       1257            |       4.65556
248             |       1276            |       5.14516
272             |       1274            |       4.68382
265             |       1208            |       4.55849
240             |       1224            |       5.1
239             |       1163            |       4.86611
```

As you can see, the distributor call overhead incurs around a 4.5-5x slowdown (compared to the required transformation from pointer to non-`const` to pointer to `const`). Still, is there any clear ways of improving this while staying within the given design pattern?

The handlers should be given `shared_ptr`s since I want them to be able to keep a reference to the passed object if they so desire. But they may or may not actually want to keep a reference to it.

I wonder if there is some way to eek out a bit more performance by avoiding `shared_ptr` copy construction, but I'm not sure of the best way to do that.

**EDIT**: There are a few aspects of this design that are very important to me. They are as follows:

1. My actual use case requires that the original `shared_ptr` *must* be a pointer to non-`const`, and the `shared_ptr` received by the handler *must* be a pointer to `const`. Therefore, I am essentially comparing the cost of the `distribute` call against the cost of calling a function which incurs that transformation as a reference point.
2. The users of the `Distributor` class should *not* need to worry about casting. Any casting to `Base` and back to a `Derived` class should be invisible to the user.
3. I would like to support handler functions of pretty much any variety (lambdas, functors, member functions, function pointers, etc) though if the performance benefits of being more restrictive are significant that may change my mind.

Efficency improvements in other aspects of the code (like registering listeners) are welcome as well but are not as essential. What is of greatest concern is having the `Distributor` call all of the listeners as efficiently as possible.

Comment: `std::make_shared<Derived>()` vs `std::make_unique<Derived>()` -- almost all of your time is actually spent allocating memory, and the slow one allocates memory twice, so is roughly 2x as slow.  `unique_ptr` can be converted to a `shared_ptr`, but that requires a memory allocation for the RC block.  Direct call to `make_shared` causes the RC block to be allocated contiguously with the object.  As with most microbenchmarks, you aren't measuring what you care about.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Thank you for pointing that out! That was an error in my code. I've updated it to be consistent across tests. That improves the results considerably.

Comment: One thing that comes to my mind is changing parameters to take `shared_ptr` by const reference, in order to avoid incrementing/decrementing counter.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your current solution still allocates a lot, so you measure allocation speed, not function call speed. Remove the `make_shared` call from the inner loop, and you'll see that the difference between raw/`std::function` call is much higher.

Comment: @geza that was another error on my part. Shouldn't have been measuring the allocation. I should have realized that with Yakk's comment... But anyway, thank you! This has been rectified.

Comment: Further problem: `evt` is a non-const Derived pointer, but the function takes a const one, so there is a "hidden" shader_ptr conversion, which takes time. If you remove this, you'll see that the compiler removes the whole raw func test, as it does nothing. If I make the compiler not inline `handleDerived`, then the difference is 16 vs 300, ratio: 19.1

Comment: @geza Yes, although this trivial example does not, my actual use case requires this to happen. The original shared_ptr *must* be a pointer to non-const, and the pointer received by the handler *must* be a pointer to const. I will mention that restriction.

Comment: Also, I just fixed another error where the `distribute` function was grabbing the type of the *pointer* instead of the type of the *object*. As a result, the handler attached to the distributor wasn't being called at all. This has been fixed. Now the slowdowns are around where I expected.

Answer (score 2):

A side note:

When a function takes `std::shared_ptr` by value that involves chasing a pointer (a potential cache miss) and an atomic increment (a relatively expensive operation). Avoid taking `std::shared_ptr` by value.

For start, change:

```
void distribute(std::shared_ptr<const Base> basePtr)
```

to:

```
void distribute(std::shared_ptr<const Base> const& basePtr)
```

And then in other places.

---

At high level though, you compare the cost of direct call to `handleDerived` to a call that:

- does a `typeid` call,
- hash lookup,
- iteration over a vector,
- virtual call,
- call through a function pointer.

That is a lot of overhead. You can reduce it a bit by avoiding those virtual calls:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <typeindex>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <chrono>

struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() {};
};
struct Derived :  Base {};

class Distributor
{
public:
    template <class T, typename F>
    void addHandler(F&& handler) {
        handlerMap[std::type_index(typeid(T))].emplace_back(std::forward<F>(handler));
    }

    void distribute(std::shared_ptr<const Base> const& basePtr) {
        std::type_index typeIdx(typeid(*basePtr));
        for(auto& handler : handlerMap[typeIdx])
            handler(basePtr);
    }

private:
    std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::vector<std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<const Base> const&)>>> handlerMap;
};

void handleDerived(std::shared_ptr<const Derived> const&) { }

int main ()
{
    size_t iters = 10000000;
    size_t numRuns = 10;

    Distributor distributor;

    // add our test handler
    distributor.addHandler<Derived>([](std::shared_ptr<const Base> const& p) { 
        handleDerived(std::static_pointer_cast<const Derived>(p)); 
    });

    std::cout << "Raw Func Call\t|\tDistributor\t|\tRatio" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "-------------\t|\t-----------\t|\t-----" << std::endl;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < numRuns; i++)
    {
        auto evt = std::make_shared<Derived>();

        // time raw function calls
        auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        for (size_t i = 0; i < iters; i++) {
            handleDerived(evt);
        }
        auto d = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start);

        // time calls through the distributor
        start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        for (size_t i = 0; i < iters; i++) {
            distributor.distribute(evt);
        }
        auto d2 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start);

        std::cout << d.count() << "\t\t|\t" << d2.count() << "\t\t|\t" << (d2*1.0/d) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Raw Func Call   |       Distributor     |       Ratio
-------------   |       -----------     |       -----
72              |       238             |       3.30556
72              |       238             |       3.30556
72              |       238             |       3.30556
72              |       238             |       3.30556
72              |       238             |       3.30556
72              |       238             |       3.30556
72              |       238             |       3.30556
72              |       238             |       3.30556
72              |       238             |       3.30556
72              |       238             |       3.30556
```

On my machine the initial ratio was 4.5.

Comment: This does indeed improve performance. I changed the `distribute` function and `handle` functions as you suggested and now I'm seeing around a 4x ish slowdown. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, I expect to incur some overhead. What I'm asking is for help *minimizing* that overhead. Though, as I think was mentioned in the comments, the call to `handleDerived` doesn't quite inline to 0 because it has to convert `shared_ptr<Derived>` to `shared_ptr<const Derived>`, which is why the compiler can't eliminate it completely.

Comment: @NanoWizard You are quite right about that cast. Updated the answer for you.

Comment: This is a very useful comparison. However, there are certain aspects to the design I wouldn't want to give up which you have removed. For instance, it is important to me that any casting to `Base` and back to `Derived` be invisible to users of the `Distributor` class. Still, this is very nice to get an idea of how much those virtual calls cost me in terms of performance. Thank you!